# constraintLayout keyframe animation on fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, android-transitions

I have recently came across to this video [Keyframe Animations with ConstraintLayout and ConstraintSet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHcfs6rStRo) , it seems pretty cool . so Implemented this way following the steps showed in a [blog post](https://proandroiddev.com/creating-awesome-animations-using-constraintlayout-and-constraintset-part-i-390cc72c5f75) . There is just one difference though between the blog and my use case . I am working with fragment . I thought theoretically implementation supposed to be as it is . Here is my work around for keyframe animation on two [constrainSet()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html)

**ConstrainLayout initial (point A so to speak)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragment_root">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.687" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/missing_permission"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.476" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/setting_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:text="@string/settings"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.511" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ConstrainLayout initial (point B the destination , the final look of the layout)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragment_root">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/missing_permission"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.858" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/setting_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="164dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="@string/settings"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Here is my fragment with keyframe transition code**

```
var goToSettings: () -> Unit = {}

private lateinit var root: ConstraintLayout

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
        = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nocamera_permission_fragment_alt, container, false).also {
    root = it.findViewById(R.id.fragment_root)
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) =
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState).run {
            setting_button.setOnClickListener { goToSettings() }

            val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
            constraintSet.clone(activity, R.layout.nocamera_permission_fragment)

            val transition = ChangeBounds().apply {
                interpolator = OvershootInterpolator()
                duration = 1000
            }

            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(root, transition)
            constraintSet.applyTo(root)
        }
```

I has no effect on the layout , app renders the final layout `R.layout.nocamera_permission_fragment` after run . Does anybody have any idea ?

Comment: I had same issue I wonder if you solved it. I added handler with delay onResume to  start animation and it works but its workaround would be cool to start animation on lunch...

Comment: I am running into the same issue, and seems the answer below points out the reason but still not an elegant resolution. Looking forward to see a better solution, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You are applying transition too soon (View is not even attached to window yet and had no layout pass), so delayed transition is discarded. Try using `post` instead of `run`.

Comment: I think this makes sense, as after I use `view.post { constraint animation function here } `, so I am wondering what the reason for down voting, anyone can explain? Thanks.